# Get the most frequent pairs that share a special value

Tags: sparql

This is my first time with SPARQL and I’m working on an ontology for movies and actors.

- I have `Movie` and `Actor` classes, and each instance of movie has actors.
- The `Actor` class has the object property `hasGender` which tells if an actor is Male or Female.

I need a query to return the pairs of male and female actors who worked together most frequently.

I wrote query return the most frequent Male Actor:

```
PREFIX ontology: <https://....../>
SELECT ?Actor (count (?Movie) as ?MoviesCount)
WHERE { 
    ?Movie ontology:hasActor ?Actor.
    ?Actor ontology:hasGender ?Gender
  filter regex (str(?Gender), "Male")
 }
Group by ?Actor
Order by desc (?MoviesCount)
```

I wrote query return the most frequent Female Actor:

```
PREFIX ontology: <https://....../>
SELECT ?Actor (count (?Movie) as ?MoviesCount)
WHERE { 
    ?Movie ontology:hasActor ?Actor.
    ?Actor ontology:hasGender ?Gender
  filter regex (str(?Gender), "Female")
 }
Group by ?Actor
Order by desc (?MoviesCount)
```

But that is not what I need.

I need only one query which should return 3 values:

1. The Actor
2. The Actress
3. The Movies count which the pair worked on together

Answer (score 1):

You can combine both of your queries by making the query variable `?Actor` gender-specific (e.g., `?actor` and `?actress`).

```
SELECT ?actress ?actor (COUNT(?movie) as ?movie_count)

WHERE { 

  ?movie 
    ontology:hasActor ?actress ;
    ontology:hasActor ?actor .

  ?actress ontology:hasGender ?female .
  ?actor ontology:hasGender ?male .

  FILTER regex(str(?female), "Female") .
  FILTER regex(str(?male), "Male") .
  
}
GROUP BY ?actress ?actor
ORDER BY DESC (?movie_count)
```

Instead of using a `FILTER`, you can directly specify the gender value:

```
# if it’s an object:
?actress ontology:hasGender <the URI of your "Female" concept> .

# if it’s a string:
?actress ontology:hasGender "Female" .

# if it’s a language-tagged string:
?actress ontology:hasGender "Female"@en .
```